# How to validate a random sample

Tags: sampling, randomness

I have been given two sets of data, one with 10,000 observations which is a subset of the other with 100,000 observations. It is **claimed** that the small dataset is a random sample of the large dataset.

How do I verify whether this is true?

I could compare the distributions, e.g. mean/median/interquartile ranges for different variables in both sets of data. However, is there a general way to test the hypothesis: "dataset x is not randomly sampled from dataset y."

Comment: I'm brought to mind of a [certain problem](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/). Now, if you have a particular kind of nonrandomness in mind, there are ways to look for it (but even then, it could actually happen randomly, just like that random number generator).

Comment: funny, but I see your point. I guess I am after a multivariable Kolmogorov-Smirnov test?

Comment: Oh. Such things certainly exist - not just KS tests but other kinds of goodness of fit.

Comment: e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#The_Kolmogorov.E2.80.93Smirnov_statistic_in_more_than_one_dimension). The problem is such tests don't do what you actually asked for: you asked how to *verify that the claim is true*. The test can't do that (which is why I didn't suggest it - you asked for something it won't do). It can sometimes give you a pretty clear indication that it's false, but failure to reject is not the same thing as verifying that it's true.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. However, is there a set of tests you would consider (like K-S), and if the two datasets fail to reject the null in all the tests, then you are 'satisfied' and don't check any further. (For example, in my particular dataset, I was happy to stop at comparing the distributions of two continuous variables separately. But: Perhaps I should check some sort of covariance measure of these two variables?)

Comment: Do you mean 10,000 and 100,000 records (rows)? Variables are columns in a dataset.

Comment: You can *always* appear to falsify such a claim by dredging the data to find some statistic that differs so much between the sample and the population that it would be "unlikely" to be observed in random sampling.  The difficulty is that there is no quantitative control over the number of different statistics that could be constructed to test the randomization. Thus this kind of evaluation is more art than science and is typically carried out with some diffidence and employed primarily to check there were not any huge errors made in the sampling.